# How should we handle tags for particles?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm all about tagging - once this site gets big, it's going to be awesome to be able to say "give me all the questions related to the particle と".

I've started tagging particle questions accordingly: [particle-to](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-to), [particle-ni](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-ni), etc.

I wanted to just put "to" in romaji, but the StackExchange engine wouldn't let me (probably because it's the English "to").  Is there a way around this?  Or do people agree with my "prefixing" of the word particle?

Answer (score 3):

hmm, sounds like overdoing things.

A particle is a grammar point. So the tags "grammar" and/or "particle" should be enough.

Comment: Right - but thinking about beginners, I think it'd be great to view all the questions related to a single particle.  You'd probably be able to get a really strong sense of it then.  Additionally, there are probably only ~10 or so, so I don't think the number of tags can get out of hand.

Comment: i agree with makdad that it will be great for beginners learning about a specific particle.  

However, for everyone else i think it is overkill.

Can we have synonymns where all the particle-to and particle-nis get grouped under one tag called "particles"?

Comment: Good question - not sure if that's possible.  Maybe for now just tag both?  Argh that's a pain... "particles" and "particle-ni".